# How to do a conditional write in dynamodb transactions using boto3 python library

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have two documents in dynamodb with `Id` as hash key (no range key)
one document looks like this

```
{
  'Id': 'x',
  'ExpiresAt': 1634889543
}
```

another document looks like below

```
{
  'Id': 'y',
  'counter': 1
}
```

If the document with id `x` does not exist or it exists but `expires_at` is less than current time, then I want to increment counter in document with id `y`. I believe I have to use transactions.
I found this article where they tell us how to do this using a transaction manager library in `Java` - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/performing-conditional-writes-using-the-amazon-dynamodb-transaction-library/
But I couldn't find anything where they explain how to do this in python. How can I achieve this in python using Boto3?

Answer (score -1):

Use query to find the current status of document with 'Id':x and the update the other document using UpdateExpression with "ADD"

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
from datetime import datetime

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('your_table_name')

result = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('Id').eq('x')
)

if result is None or result['ExpiresAt'] < datetime.now():
    table.update_item(
        Key={
            "Id": "y"
        },
        UpdateExpression='ADD counter :inc',
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':inc': {'N': '1'}
        }
    )
```

Comment: I want both operations to be done atomically. That's why using transactions. Doing one after the other won't help my purpose